# I have type issue with my React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My React component is like this:

```
export default function Player() {
  const [enteredPlayerName, setEnteredPlayerName] = useState();
  const playerName = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  function handleSubmitName() {
    if (playerName.current) {
      setEnteredPlayerName(playerName.current.value); // at this line i get type error
    }
  }

  return (
    <section id="player">
      <h1>Welcome {enteredPlayerName ?? "Unknown entity"}</h1>
      <p>
        <input type="text" ref={playerName} />
        <button onClick={handleSubmitName}>Set Name</button>
      </p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Error content:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<undefined>.ts(2345)
```

What type  must I use on `useRef()` for fixing this error?

Comment: You need to define the type for your useState hook. As it is a type mismatch problem. `useState<string | undefined>(undefined)`

Comment: thnx for editing question and answering the question m8

Comment: @Adil there's no point adding the `undefined`s, React infers `T | undefined` if you don't supply a default value.

Answer (score 1):

You should type the state as per the error suggestion. The value you are setting is a string type, so this is what the state should be declared as. You can let Typescript infer the type however just by providing an initial value, e.g. `useState("")`, or if your Type system is a little older, explicitly type it, e.g. `useState<string>("")`. Note that in both cases you still provide a valid initial value.

```
export default function Player() {
  const [enteredPlayerName, setEnteredPlayerName] = useState("");
  const playerName = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  function handleSubmitName() {
    if (playerName.current) {
      setEnteredPlayerName(playerName.current.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <section id="player">
      <h1>Welcome {enteredPlayerName || "Unknown entity"}</h1>
      <p>
        <input type="text" ref={playerName} />
        <button onClick={handleSubmitName}>Set Name</button>
      </p>
    </section>
  );
}
```